# OSX file navigation for pictures like windows

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, preview

In windows I can hold control and use my arrow keys. When I find a file I want to be included in the group selection I hit the space bar(I think this is how it works) and it will add to the selected list of items.

I'm not working by file name, I'm working by picture preview. So the ability to scroll through the list and see previews is important while group selecting. I'm trying to delete pictures. I have thousands in one folder. Should I use win32 to do this? or am I just missing how to do it with OSX?

Answer (score 1):

I often select images to keep or delete by generating HTML files like this:

`printf %s\\n ~/Pictures/folder/*.jpg|while read l;do printf %s "<a href=$l><img src=$l height=469></a>";done>/tmp/a.html;open /tmp/a.html`

Then I for example move the files I opened in tabs to another folder:

`osascript -e 'set text item delimiters to linefeed' -e 'tell app "Safari" to URL of tabs of window 1 as text'|cut -d/ -f3-|xargs gmv -t ~/Desktop`

Comment: This is really cool. I will check it out, but it's still going to be easier to boot up my windows install with bootcamp.

Answer (score 1):

Well, unless there is specific reason why you want to delete all the selected pictures at once, you could just flip through them in the finder (using Cover Flow view in the finder) and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> the images you want to delete as you come across them.

This will effectively move each chosen image to the Trash.

Comment: I don't actually want to delete them. I want to say pick 600 pictures and move them to specific folders. I can't find a way to keep my selected files while flipping through files with cover flow view. 

Imagine I have pictures 1 through 2000 and I want to pick 600 pictures that are of me and my girlfriend. While going through each picture file by file and viewing with cover flow I'm trying to select a file if it pertains to me and my girlfriend. I can't do this without losing my selected files. My solution at the moment is to copy all of the files to a thumb drive and sort them using windows.